# OAuth 2.0 provider implementation for Scala/Lift

Tags: scala, lift, oauth-2.0

Does anyone know of a OAuth 2.0 provider (server side) implementation for Scala/Lift? I see Scala 2.0 client, but no provider.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there is one readily available. So I think you have two options:

1. Implement one yourself.
2. Use a [Java library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/) in Scala. However this is probably not the optimal root due to the obvious impedance mismatch. But, I don't see much other choice. The project has both an OAuth client/[server](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/source/browse/#svn/code/java/core/provider) library and an [example](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/source/browse/#svn/code/java/example/oauth-provider) on how to use it.

Comment: what do you mean by impedance mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

Check this question:

[OAuth2 provider for Scalatra or Play framework in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639055/oauth2-provider-for-scalatra-or-play-framework-in-scala)

So far, I have found https://github.com/nulab/scala-oauth2-provider and it works good for me. However, I have used it with Play Framework https://github.com/tuxdna/play-oauth2-server.

Answer (score 0):

this library may help [Scala-OAuth](https://github.com/jmichalicek/Scala-OAuth)

Comment: This is a client library... OP is looking to make an OAuth provider.